# how to add copy of block "discount" in checkout magento

Tags: xml, magento

I need to add block (copy of block discount in shoppcard) under existing block. I have some code, but I am nubby and don't know what I must to add in my config.xml and  phtml file. So, i created file config.xml(still empty) in directory ***local/Andrew/Catrt2/ect***
And to add layuot and template in directories 
***frontend/andrew/default/layout/coupon.xml***
with code

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
 <!-- Root node for Magento layout configuration -->
  <layout version="0.1.0">
   <default>
    <reference name="checkout.cart">
        <block type="andrew/cart2_coupon2" name="checkout.cart2.coupon2"   as="coupon2" template="coupon2/view.phtml" after="checkout/cart/coupon"/>
    </reference>
   </default>
  </layout>
```

and
***frontend/andrew/default/templat/view.phtml***(empty to)
Sorry for a bad English:)

Comment: Do you want to add new block on cart page after coupon form ?

Comment: Yes, And new block it is a copy of coupon block